# how to access external files that are not in the web app folder using apache server

Tags: java, apache, jar, java-web-start, jnlp

I have developed a JAVA webstart application using JNLP,am planning access jar files related jnlp from the outside webapp folder how to access those jar files.

Answer (score 1):

> jar files related jnlp from the outside webapp folder

Jars in the web app. directory are never meant for client distribution.  They stay on the server and are protected.

A Java Web Start app. obviously needs to download all the Jars and related resources to the *client*, so every one of those resources must be available by URL on a **public** part of the server.  Always make sure you can fetch the resource (Jar, JNLP, icons  etc.) using a direct link in your favorite browser.  If it does not allow it, neither will it work in JWS apps.